# relation between harris detector results in matlab and opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am working on corner feature detection using harris detector. I wrote  program detect feature in image in matlab using  following code  to detect harris feature

```
corners = detectHarrisFeatures(img, 'MinQuality', 0.0001); 
S = corners.selectStrongest(100);
```

then I transfer  all program from matlab to opencv

I used following code to detect harris corner points

```
int thresh = 70;

for( int j = 0; j < dst_norm.rows && cont < 100; j++ )
{  
    for( int i = 0; i < dst_norm.cols && cont < 100; i++ )
    {
        if((int) dst_norm.at<float>(j, i) > thresh )
        {                        
            S.at<int>(cont, 0) = i;
            S.at<int>(cont, 1) = j;
            I.at<int>(cont, 0) = i;
            I.at<int>(cont, 1) = j;

            cont = cont + 1;                            
        }
    }
}
```

extracted region was different in both program and I discovered that  harris detected corner points in matlab  not as harris detected corner points in opencv.

How can I make detected corner points from both programs are same?

Answer (score 1):

Is `dst_norm` an array of Harris corner metric values? In that case you are choosing first 100 pixels with the corner metric above the threshold, which is incorrect.

In your MATLAB code, `detectHarrisFeatures` finds points which are local maxima of the corner metric. Then `selectStrongest` method selects 100 of those points with the highest metric. So, first you have to find the local maxima. Then you have to sort them, and take the top 100.

Even then, the results will not be exactly the same, because `detectHarrisFeatures` locates the corners with sub-pixel accuracy, using interpolation.